# bad time argument filename in tmpwatch

Tags: shell, unix

While executing the `tmpwatch` to clean the `tmp` directory in Unix, we are getting the error:

```
 error: bad time argument filename.
```

But the same command working in another server. Please suggest ways to resolve the issue.

Comment: There's nothing we can do to help you with the information in the question, is there?  There's no example of the code you're using, whether working or not.  There must be a difference between the two servers if the same code works on one and fails on the other — you will need to track down what that difference is.  It would be worth identifying which variant of Unix you are using, and where the `tmpwatch` command comes from — it is not a POSIX standard command.

Comment: Compare `/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch` file of both the servers

Answer (score 1):

/etc/cron.daily/tmpwatch is a very picky file that will cry when the syntax is not just right.

Take a look at your exclusion list.

If you have an absolute file name or directory name:

```
-x /tmp/filename
```

If you have a wildcard:

```
-X '/tmp/file*'
```

Not having the correct switch or/and not having the single quotes around the path with the wildcard in it will produce a bad time argument error.